# Local & Remote OWL/SPARQL queries with Jena

Tags: java, sparql, owl, jena, protege

I want to create a simple application using Jena and SPARQL, that inserts, deletes, updates, and queries some OWL/RDF data. I worked on Protégé to create the ontology and noticed SPARQL in it,
but I want to run SPARQL queries programatically with Jena in Java.

1. I saw “[Using Jena to create a SPARQL query on DBpedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267333/using-jena-to-create-a-sparql-query-on-dbpedia)” and I know how to use SPARQL with Jena, but I want to upload it to server or to work on localhost or whatever.
2. SPARQL doesn't support operations like update or insert, but only querying. Are there any other languages/methods that support these operations, or should I manipulate data manually in java in each application?
3. How can I upload my ontology, preferably with something related to Protégé?
   I tried [Protege2Joseki](http://semweb.krasu.ru/protege2joseki/) but couldn't get it to work.
4. Are RDF-stores just for RDF? I am working on OWL files. For example, if I am using MySQL as an RDF-store, would it also work for OWL concepts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that on Stack Overflow you should really ask one question per posting. Asking four questions at once makes it hard for you to indicate when you have got the answer you're looking for.

Answering your questions in turn:

1. It sounds like you want a endpoint loaded with your queries and ontologies which you and others can query using SPARQL. For this, you can use [Joseki](http://joseki.sourceforge.net/).
2. The [SPARQL working group at W3C](http://www.w3.org/2009/sparql/wiki/Main_Page) is currently standardising update extensions to the SPARQL language. Some of the existing query engines, including [the one in Jena](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/index.html), already implement the proposed update mechanisms as SPARQL extensions.
3. I don't understand question 3.
4. Yes, an RDF-triple store can store OWL, because OWL is a specialisation of RDF that provides additional semantic representations. Many tools, including Jena, [provide specialised APIs](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/) for storing, retrieving and manipulating OWL constructs stored in RDF triple stores.

Comment: oh thank you Ian Dickinson , I really found what I wanted. I used SWRL instead of SPARQL since I am interested  in queries at higher level than triples level. thank you again

Comment: You're welcome. Please click the 'accept answer' button to show that you have the response you were looking for - that's how StackOverflow helps other people to find the answers to questions which may have been asked before.

Comment: oh amazing system of stackOverflow o.o"