# How to build SPARQL queries in java?

Tags: java, string, sparql

Is there a library, which is able to build SPARQL queries programmatically like the `CriteriaBuilder` in JPA or to build the queries like with a `PreparedStatement` for SQL?

Similar (for SQL): [Cleanest way to build an SQL string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370818/cleanest-way-to-build-an-sql-string-in-java)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can build queries programmatically in Jena using two methods: syntax or algebra. There's an [introduction](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/manipulating_sparql_using_arq.html) in the jena wiki.

Using the algebra you'd do something like:

```
Op op;
BasicPattern pat = new BasicPattern();                 // Make a pattern
pat.add(pattern);                                      // Add our pattern match
op = new OpBGP(pat);                                   // Make a BGP from this pattern
op = OpFilter.filter(e, op);                           // Filter that pattern with our expression
op = new OpProject(op, Arrays.asList(Var.alloc("s"))); // Reduce to just ?s
Query q = OpAsQuery.asQuery(op);                       // Convert to a query
q.setQuerySelectType();                                // Make is a select query
```

(taken from the wiki page)

It's not `CriteriaBuilder` (nor was it intended to be), but is some of the way there. You `OpJoin` rather than AND, `OpUnion` when you want to OR, etc. The pain points are expressions in my experience: you probably want to parse them from a string.

Answer (score 7):

The recent versions of Jena have added a `StringBuilder` style API for building query/update strings and parameterizing them if desired.

This class is called [`ParameterizedSparqlString`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/ParameterizedSparqlString.html), here's an example of using it to create a query:

```
ParameterizedSparqlString queryStr = new ParameterizedSparqlString();
queryStr.setNSPrefix("sw", "http://skunkworks.example.com/redacted#");
queryStr.append("SELECT ?a ?b ?c ?d");
queryStr.append("{");
queryStr.append("   ?rawHit sw:key");
queryStr.appendNode(someKey);
queryStr.append(".");
queryStr.append("  ?rawHit sw:a ?a .");
queryStr.append("  ?rawHit sw:b ?b .");
queryStr.append("  ?rawHit sw:c ?c . ");
queryStr.append("  ?rawHit sw:d ?d .");
queryStr.append("} ORDER BY DESC(d)");

Query q = queryStr.asQuery();
```

**Disclaimer** - I'm the developer who contributed this functionality to Jena

See [What's the best way to parametize SPARQL queries?](https://web.archive.org/web/20150512231123/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/12147/whats-the-best-way-to-parameterize-sparql-queries?#18463) for more discussion on doing this across various APIs.

Answer (score 4):

I implemented [SPARQL Java](https://bitbucket.org/rehei/sparql-java) - a kind of DSL for writing SPARQL queries in Java.

It solves the problem with IDE's auto formatting of concatenated SPARQL query strings and things like that.

As for example:

```
String shortQuery = Q.prefix("books", "http://example.org/books#")
            .select("?book ?authorName", new where() {
                {
                    $("?book books:author ?author");
                    $("?author books:authorName ?authorName");
                }
            }).get();
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently started to use [Sesame query builder](http://rdf4j.org/sesame/2.7/apidocs/org/openrdf/queryrender/builder/QueryBuilder.html). It looks promising except it doesn't provide much documentation and I struggled to find examples. Here is simple sample which may help you to get started:

```
ParsedTupleQuery query = QueryBuilderFactory
            .select("pubProperty", "pubPropertyValue")
                .group()
                    .atom(cmResource(resourceId), LinkPublicationsTransformation.REFERENCE_URI, "pubUri")
                    .atom("pubUri", "pubProperty", "pubPropertyValue")
                    .filter(isLiteral("pubPropertyValue"))
                .closeGroup()
            .query();
```

Just note that `isLiteral` and `cmResource` are my own little static helper classes. `isLiteral` stands for `new IsLiteral(new Var("..."))` for example where the latter one create URI with my heavily used prefix.

You might be then also interested in `SPARQLQueryRenderer` which can turn `ParsedQuery` into `String` which may be convenient for further usage.

If you end up using `String(Builder)` approach what I discourage you to do have at least a look on `RenderUtils` from `sesame-queryrendered` which has all the convenient methods to add `<` `>` around URIs, escape special characters etc.

Comment: This answer is somewhat out of date: this QueryBuilder is now obsolete and has been replaced by the RDF4J SparqlBuilder instead - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7303298/451941

Answer (score 2):

The [Eclipse RDF4J framework](https://rdf4j.org/) (the successor of Sesame) offers a Repository API which is somewhat similar to JDBC - it allows you to create a prepared Query object and inject variable bindings before executing it:

```
String query = "SELECT * WHERE {?X ?P ?Y }";
TupleQuery preparedQuery = conn.prepareQuery(QuerLanguage.SPARQL, query);
preparedQuery.setBinding("X", someValue);
...
TupleQueryResult result = preparedQuery.evaluate();
```

In addition, RDF4J has a [SparqlBuilder](https://rdf4j.eclipse.org/documentation/sparqlbuilder/) (originally known as spanqit) - a Java DSL for SPARQL which allows you to create SPARQL queries in code like this:

```
query.prefix(foaf).select(name)
    .where(x.has(foaf.iri("name"), name))
    .orderBy(name)
    .limit(5)
    .offset(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just released a beta project to do just this, called [Spanqit](https://github.com/anqit/spanqit).

I strove for readability and an intuitive interface, for example, here is some example Spanqit syntax for creating a query:

```java
query.prefix(foaf).select(name)
    .where(x.has(foaf.iri("name"), name))
    .orderBy(name)
    .limit(5)
    .offset(10);
```

Check it out, and feel free to comment and suggest improvements!

Comment: Any luck? I'd love some feedback!

Comment: Not until now, but thanks for the reminder. I will test it soon

Comment: This project has been adopted by the Eclipse Foundation project RDF4J, check out documentation here: http://docs.rdf4j.org/sparqlbuilder/

Answer (score 1):

Jena provides a QueryBuilder in the Extras package.

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/extras/querybuilder/index.html

It does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Jena Semantic Framework](http://jena.sourceforge.net/) ([SPARQL documentation](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/index.html)).  Also take a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267333/using-jena-to-create-a-sparql-query-on-dbpedia).  Sadly, its syntax is closer to a SQL PreparedStatement than to the JPA.

Comment: but the syntax used on the linked question is the thing i want to avoid

Comment: Ok.  I misunderstood your question.  I've found other links talking about a library called "Empire" that is a JPA-like interface that uses SPARQL under the covers (http://weblog.clarkparsia.com/2010/01/11/empire-05/) but I've not been able to find the source code at github.

Comment: I've finally found it at https://github.com/mhgrove/Empire but I've never used it before. I hope it fits your needs, despite it seems hard to start using it: http://weblog.clarkparsia.com/2010/05/07/rdf-for-fun-and-profit-using-empire