# Query DBpedia to get meta-data for Books

Tags: java, sparql, dbpedia, isbn

I have a bunch of ISBN's. I want to query `DBpedia` and get the meta-data of the books.

I am unable to understand the `SPARQL`.

Can someone tell me how can I get the meta-data of a book from `DBpedia` in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPARQL is both a query language and a protocol to query so-called *SPARQL endpoints*.

A SPARQL query that asks DBpedia for a book (or books) that have the ISBN 0-553-05250-0, and its (or their) associated properties and values is this:

```
select distinct ?book ?prop ?obj 
where {
  ?book a dbo:Book .
  ?book ?prop ?obj .
  ?book dbp:isbn ?isbn .
  FILTER (regex(?isbn, "0-553-05250-0"))
} 
LIMIT 100
```

See the result of the query in your browser [here](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20?book%20?prop%20?obj%20%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?book%20a%20dbpedia-owl:Book%20.%0D%0A%20%20?book%20?prop%20?obj%20.%0D%0A%20%20?book%20dbpprop:isbn%20?isbn%20.%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28regex%28?isbn,%20%220-553-05250-0%22%29%29%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0ALIMIT%20100&format=text/html&timeout=0&debug=on).

Be aware that `regex(?isbn, "0-553-05250-0")` takes some time to evaluate. It may not work for all ISBNs, because

- Wikipedia may never have a complete list of ISBNs, so neither may DBpedia
- the same ISBN without dashes will not match a query with dashes.

Also, I [noticed](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20?book%20?isbn%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?book%20a%20dbpedia-owl:Book%20.%0D%0A%20%20?book%20dbpedia-owl:isbn%20?isbn%20.%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0ALIMIT%20100&format=text/html&timeout=0&debug=on) that some ISBNs are just a string of digits and dashes, others have "ISBN" in it or "(paperback)" appended.

You can send this query to the [DBpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) via the webform (by visiting the endpoint with your browser) via [Jena](http://jena.apache.org), a well-known Java toolkit for RDF and SPARQL.
Here is the query in some Java code that queries DBpedia for results and prints them to the command line (based on another [Jena, SPARQL and DBpedia related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267333/using-jena-to-create-a-sparql-query-on-dbpedia), of which there are many):

```
String sparqlQueryString1= "select distinct ?book ?prop ?obj " +
       "where { " +
       "  ?book a dbpedia-owl:Book . " +
       "  ?book ?prop ?obj . " +
       "  ?book dbpprop:isbn ?isbn . " +
       "  FILTER (regex(?isbn, \"0-553-05250-0\")) " +
       "} " +
       "LIMIT 100";

Query query = QueryFactory.create(sparqlQueryString1);
QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query);

ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);       

qexec.close() ;
```

My favourite SPARQL resource is [Lee Feigenbaum's cheat sheet](http://www.slideshare.net/LeeFeigenbaum/sparql-cheat-sheet), which is a pretty comprehensive reference. Perhaps you would like to check out the [tutorials](http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/index.html) Jena provides with its documentation.

Comment: Ben - Thanks for the answer. I have another question. Where can I get, what details can DBpedia provide to me when I give in an ISBN number? Also can I get a JSON by just entering the query in my Browser something like - https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:3772508456

Comment: You can look at some books on Wikipedia to see what is in the Infobox - that info is in DBpedia. Or use SPARQL to get [this list](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+distinct+%3Fprop+%3Flabel+%3Fdescription%0D%0Awhere+{+%0D%0A++%3Fbook+a+dbpedia-owl%3ABook+.+%0D%0A++%3Fbook+%3Fprop+%3Fobj+.+%0D%0A++OPTIONAL+{%0D%0A++++%3Fprop+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel+.%0D%0A++}+.%0D%0A++OPTIONAL+{%0D%0A++++%3Fprop+rdfs%3Acomment+%3Fdescription+.%0D%0A++}%0D%0A}+%0D%0ALIMIT+1000&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on) of properties of books with labels and descriptions.

Comment: The DBpedia endpoint provides JSON output as described in the W3C Note [Serializing SPARQL Query Results in JSON](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-json-res/). However, it's more like a table of results serialised in JSON than it is a 'direct' JSON description like Google's Book API returns.

Comment: Ben - I have about 600,000 ISBN's. I tried to lookup for about a random 30 and there was no result. Also the the example you have given gives out a lot data which is difficult to figure out. For eg. It gives out 2 ISBN's and the title in various languages. I would like to find out the exact book against the ISBN and its details like publisher, authors, place, etc. Could you please help me on this?

Comment: I'm afraid the data in DBpedia isn't fine-grained enough for your application. ISBNs are associated with specific editions of books, but DBpedia has no notion of editions. You could take a look at the [APIs of OpenLibrary](http://openlibrary.org/developers/api) (disclosure: I am a user of/volunteer for OpenLibrary). It has editions and many ISBNs although you'll find ISBNs missing as well.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, Wikipedia does not have an ISBN search.

Wikipedia has [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3aBookSources) for using other ISBN search engines.

Amazon.com has an ISBN search [here](http://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Search-Books/b?ie=UTF8&node=241582011).  I couldn't find an API for automating the ISBN search on Amazon.