# How to read structured data from Wikipedia using its JSON response

Tags: java, json, api, information-extraction

Wikipedia has unstructured and structured information about any topic. I specially want to get structured data which is always displayed at the right side of an article. This side contains different data as you can see in an example below:

```
Country Turkey
Region  Central Anatolia
Province    Ankara
Area
 • Capital City 2,516 km2 (971 sq mi)
Elevation   938 m (3,077 ft)
Population (2011)[1][2]
 • Capital City 4,338,620
 • Density  1,551/km2 (4,020/sq mi)
 • Metro    4,965,542
Time zone   EET (UTC+2)
 • Summer (DST) EEST (UTC+3)
```

[Structured data as shown in wikipedia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iGOw.png) 

How can I read that data using Java and the JSON response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Assuming Wikpedia was meant]

DBpedia [1] is a project that aims to extract structured data from Wikipedia. You can query their database using the SPARQL endpoint. You get property-value pairs, for example, you can get the structured data connected to Berlin here [2].

[1] http://wiki.dbpedia.org/
[2] http://dbpedia.org/page/Berlin

Comment: thank your response. how to get json response with java ? And do dbpedia has turkish information with turkish language (utf-8) ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283417/query-dbpedia-to-get-meta-data-for-books for a discussion on how to use the SPARQL endpoint.